# UNION SELECT error 1064 but works if executed on it's own

Tags: mysql, select, union

I've got two mySQL servers - offline is version 5.5.25, online is version 5.0.95. I am attempting to run a UNION SELECT to join two result sets together. Both queries extract the same data from the same tables using the same joins - the only difference to each is the where query. Basic syntax is:

```
(SELECT QUERY A) 
UNION 
(SELECT QUERY B) 
ORDER BY date_created DESC, subscription_rate_id ASC
```

If I run this query offline, I get this error:

> *Error Number: 1064*
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'INNER JOIN `webmaster` d ON `d`.`dupe_master_id` =
>   `webmaster`.`webmaster_id` IN' at line 16

If I run the queries separately then both of them work. If I run the whole query ONLINE, it works. This only occurs in my OFFLINE mySQL which is running the newer mySQL version of the two. I believe the error relates to query B - but the same INNER JOIN is in query A.

The query is horrendously long and not easily shortened / broken down which is why I haven't pasted it here. I will find a way to provide it if absolutely neccessary.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the full query?

Comment: Trying, but pastebin says it's under heavy load. Will post the link as soon as I've got the query up there.

Comment: You can always post your tables, sample data and then your query in a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/).

Comment: Got it up on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/asgSwMu0
The first query runs on its own. This then returns a list of IDs that are passed into the second query - you can see the webmaster_id NOT IN part. This ensures the second query cannot return results there were present in the first query (sometimes they can overlap - the system generating this query is almost as complicated as the query itself!) - then they are UNIONed to create the final data set.

Comment: I'm aliasing it already (as "d") so that I can retrieve the "main" record via the dupe_master_id column - it's part of the JOINS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the braces around

```
FROM (`webmaster`)
```

to

```
FROM `webmaster`
```

See [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/90ead/5/2) for different versions and error message.

Comment: Hi Olaf - both queries use the same initial SELECT string and JOINS to return the same set of columns - as I mention in the OP, this works on an OLDER version of mySQL and the only difference between selects A and B is the where part.

Comment: Not sure why I can only see this now - but this makes it work offline, thanks! I'm using CodeIgniter's Active Record class to generate the query so IT is adding the braces, but I'll see if I can get rid of them. If I put the query into phpMyAdmin and take them out manually, the query will execute. Appreciate the help, thanks!